# Do-While Loop goes infinite

Tags: java

I have an abstract class that contains a variable of type String declared **moneyString**

```
String moneyString;
```

It contains data something like $123,456,789

So inside the abstract class I have function

```
void convertToInt(){
    remove(',');
    remove('$');
    empMoney = Integer.parseInt(moneyString.substring(0, moneyString.length()) );
}
```

And my remove function

```
void remove(char character){
    boolean moreFound = true;
    String tempString;
    int index;
    do{
        index = moneyString.indexOf(character);
        tempString = moneyString;
        if(index!=-1){
            //From beggining to the character
            moneyString = moneyString.substring(0,index);
            //After the character to the end
            tempString = tempString.substring(index,tempString.length());
            moneyString += tempString;
        }
        else{
            moreFound = false;
        }

    } while(moreFound);

} //END remove()
```

Isn't it supposed to get out of the loop when when moreFound = false?

Comment: You shouldn't have data like this in the first place. It should be a `BigDecimal` field and you should add the `$` and the `,` when you format it for output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is here,

```
tempString = tempString.substring(index,tempString.length());
```

Should be `index + 1` because you *don't* want to include that character.

```
tempString = tempString.substring(index + 1,tempString.length());
```

But, I suggest you use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and [`parse(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) the value. Like,

```
public static int convertToInt(String money) throws ParseException {
    NumberFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###");
    return df.parse(money).intValue();
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println(convertToInt("$123,456,789"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output is

```
123456789
```

Comment: Yes, the index+1 seamed to be the issue, works fine until I start to parse int 123,456,789,101 (without the commas)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you have to change the line:

```
tempString = tempString.substring(index,tempString.length());
```

to:

```
tempString = tempString.substring(index+1,tempString.length());
```

The assignment could be done to a variable of type Long:

```
moneyString="$123,456,789,101";
long empMoney;
remove('$');
remove(',');
empMoney = Long.parseLong(moneyString.substring(0, moneyString.length()) );
```